# how to implement blocking feature like facebook and twitter

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

i am trying to build a social website and i want to implement blocking feature in this website using Laravel to allow user to block other user and when either of the users visits the other user profile will find a `404` page or try to search for the other user , the other user won't appear in search.

i have searched for any answers on the internet but i found nothing about this,
by the way i am using `Laravel with Mongodb`.

so how can i implement this feature in this social website, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This question is really way to general but think of the problem exactly the same as the 'friends' problem. You have a many-to-many relationship on the same user model i.e. a user can block zero to many users and each of those users can block zero to many, hence many to many. Google that and you'll find answers.